# Unable to dump as "pure" YAML

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

ruamel.yaml==0.15.37
Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Current code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys


yaml = YAML()
kube_context = yaml.load('''
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters: []
    contexts: []
    current-context: ''
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users: []
''')
kube_context['users'].append({'name': '{username}/{cluster}'.format(username='test', cluster='test'), 'user': {'token': 'test'}})
kube_context['clusters'].append({'name': 'test', 'cluster': {'server': 'URL:443'}})
kube_context['contexts'].append({'name': 'test', 'context': {'user': 'test', 'cluster': 'test'}})

yaml.dump(kube_context, sys.stdout)
```

My `yaml.dump()` is producing output that contains the list and dict objects, instead of being fully expanded.

Current output:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: [{name: test, cluster: {server: URL:443}}]
contexts: [{name: test, context: {user: test, cluster: test}}]
current-context: ''
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: [{name: test/test, user: {token: test}}]
```

What do I need to do in order to have `yaml.dump()` output fully expanded?

Expected output:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: 
  - name: test
    cluster: 
      server: URL:443
contexts: 
  - name: test
    context:
      user: test
      cluster: test
current-context: ''
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: 
  - name: test/test
    user: 
      token: test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ruamel.yaml`, when using the default `YAML()` or `YAML(typ='rt')` will preserve the [flow](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790088)- or [block](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2797293) style of sequences and mappings. There is no way to make a block style empty sequence or empty mapping and your `[]` and `{}` are therefore tagged as flow style when loaded.

Flow style can only contain flow style (whereas block style can contain block style or flow style) ([YAML 1.2 spec 8.2.3](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2799181)):

> YAML allows flow nodes to be embedded inside block collections (but not vice-versa).

Because of that, the dict/mapping data that you insert in the (flow-style) list/sequence will also be represented as flow-style.

If you want everything to be block style (what you call "expanded" mode), you can explicitly set that by calling the `.set_block_style()` method on the `.fa` attribute (which is only available on the collections, hence the `try`/`except`):

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys


yaml = YAML()

kube_context = yaml.load('''
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters: []
    contexts: []
    current-context: ''
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users: []
''')
kube_context['users'].append({'name': '{username}/{cluster}'.format(username='test', cluster='test'), 'user': {'token': 'test'}})
kube_context['clusters'].append({'name': 'test', 'cluster': {'server': 'URL:443'}})
kube_context['contexts'].append({'name': 'test', 'context': {'user': 'test', 'cluster': 'test'}})

for k in kube_context:
    try:
        kube_context[k].fa.set_block_style()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

yaml.dump(kube_context, sys.stdout)
```

this gives:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- name: test
  cluster:
    server: URL:443
contexts:
- name: test
  context:
    user: test
    cluster: test
current-context: ''
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: test/test
  user:
    token: test
```

Please note that it is not necessary to set `yaml.default_flow_style = False` in the default round-trip-mode; and that although block-style has been set for the value of key `preferences`, it is represented flow style as there is no other way to represent an empty mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The output is „pure“ YAML. You want the nodes to be presented in *block style* (indentation-based) as opposed to the current *flow style* ([]{}-based). Here's how to do that:

```
yaml = YAML(typ="safe")
yaml.default_flow_style = False
```

(Note Athon's comment on the `typ` below; you need to set it to `safe` or `unsafe` so that the RoundTripLoader does not set the style of the empty sequences)

Comment: This works for all `typ` "modes" except for the default (`typ='rt') mode that the OP uses. there `.default_flow_style = False` is set (as part of the setup) and works as such for newly added leaf collections under a block style collection, but not under the (empty) flow-style collections that the OP loads, as for those the style is preserved. One can argue that the style should not be set on empty collections as there is no way to make a block style empty mapping or sequence.